# How to stop outputting strings that do not contain a period?

Tags: string, autoit

I am splitting content of the clipboard and output the sub-strings one at a time. Only, I do not want to output any sub-string that does not contain a period (I want strings that do not contain a period to be ignored).

```
Func bulkload()
    $origional = ClipGet()
    Local $string = ClipGet()
    Local $arrayofsubstrings = StringSplit($string, '!')
    Local $substringcount = 1
    Local $outToClipPut
    Do
        $outToClipPut = $arrayofsubstrings[$substringcount]
        ClipPut($outToClipPut)
        Send("{CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}")
        Send(@CRLF)
        $substringcount = $substringcount + 1
        Sleep(300)
    Until $substringcount = 100
EndFunc   ;==>bulkload
```

Alternatively remove all continuous strings (no white spaces in the middle, maybe better to say, 'words') that do not contain a period from the input and set this value to `$string`. Any other way to achieve the same end is acceptable. I'm guessing my code might look something like this:

```
Func bulkload()
    $origional = ClipGet()
    Local $string = ClipGet()
    Local $arrayofsubstrings = StringSplit($string, '!')
    Local $substringcount = 1
    Local $outToClipPut
    Do
        $outToClipPut = $arrayofsubstrings[$substringcount]
        ;check for a period
        If $ouToClip = "has a period" Then
            ClipPut($outToClipPut)
            Send("{CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}")
            Send(@CRLF)
            $substringcount = $substringcount + 1
            Sleep(300)
        Else
            $substringcount = $substringcount + 1
            Sleep(300)
        EndIf
    Until $substringcount = 100
EndFunc   ;==>bulkload
```

This does not work:

```
Func bulkload()
    $origional = ClipGet()
    Local $string = ClipGet()
    Local $arrayofsubstrings = StringSplit($string, '!')
    Local $substringcount = 1
    Local $outToClipPut
    Local $searchstring = "."
    Do
        $outToClipPut = $arrayofsubstrings[$substringcount]
        If StringInStr($outToClipPut, $searchstring) Then
            ClipPut($outToClipPut)
            Send("{CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}")
            Send(@CRLF)
            $substringcount = $substringcount + 1
            Sleep(300)
        Else
            $substringcount = $substringcount + 1
            Sleep(300)
        EndIf
    Until $substringcount = 100
EndFunc   ;==>bulkload
```

i tried replaceing the my code with:

```
Func BulkLoad(Const $sDelim = '!', Const $sSearch = '.', Const $iDelay = 250)
    Local Const $sInput = ClipGet()
    Local Const $aArray = StringSplit($sInput, $sDelim)

    For $i1 = 1 To $aArray[0]

        If Not StringInStr($aArray[$i1], $sSearch) Then ContinueLoop

        ClipPut($aArray[$i1])
        Send('^v')
        Sleep($iDelay)
        Send('{ENTER}')
        Sleep($iDelay)

    Next

EndFunc
```

but i got and error like this:

[image: error]

my here is my app:

```
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <StringConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstants.au3>
#include <GuiDateTimePicker.au3>
#include <Date.au3>
#include <Array.au3>




;lets make an expiration date
$endDate = "2020/02/01"

Local $datediff = _DateDiff('D', $endDate, _NowCalc())
If $datediff > 0 Then
    MsgBox(0, "Expired", "Sorry, this program has expired, contact admin@elishahabinsky.com for an extension.", 15)
    Exit
EndIf

MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Copy a complete URL to clipboard or press Ctrl+Shift+a." & @CRLF & "Press Ctrl+Shift+d to insert multiple URLs." & @CRLF & "Page:" & @CRLF & " removes the begginning of the URL string until the domain name." & @CRLF & "Site:" & @CRLF & "select the entire domain leaving out the page specification." & @CRLF & "Ignore:" & @CRLF & "Ignore this URL." & @CRLF & "IP:" & @CRLF & "Place the IP of the domain into the clipboard." & @CRLF & "Exit:" & @CRLF & "Terminate the program." & @CRLF & "Escape Key:" & @CRLF & "Terminate the program.")


; Press Esc to terminate script, Pause/Break to "pause"

Global $g_bPaused = False

HotKeySet("{PAUSE}", "TogglePause")
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate")
HotKeySet("^+d", "BulkLoad") ; ctrl-shift-d
HotKeySet("^+a", "TrimItDown")

Func TogglePause()
    $g_bPaused = Not $g_bPaused
    While $g_bPaused
        Sleep(100)
        ToolTip('Script is "Paused"', 0, 0)
    WEnd
    ToolTip("")
EndFunc   ;==>TogglePause

Func Terminate()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>Terminate
;new funtion template
Func abc()
    ;replace this with code
EndFunc   ;==>abc
;some functions we will need:
Func altf4()
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{ALTDOWN}{F4}{ALTUP}")
    Sleep(1000)
EndFunc   ;==>altf4
;save ctrl + shift + s
Func ctrlshfts()
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{CTRLDOWN}{SHIFTDOWN}s{SHIFTUP}{CTRLUP}")
    Sleep(1000)
EndFunc   ;==>ctrlshfts
;desktop win + d
Func wind()
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{LWINDOWN}d{LWINUP}")
    Sleep(1000)
EndFunc   ;==>wind
;run win + r
Func winr()
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{LWINDOWN}r{LWINUP}")
    Sleep(1000)
EndFunc   ;==>winr
;paste control + v
Func ctrlv()
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}")
    Sleep(1000)
EndFunc   ;==>ctrlv
;copy control + c
Func ctrlc()
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}")
    Sleep(1000)
EndFunc   ;==>ctrlc
;select all control + a
Func ctrla()
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{CTRLDOWN}a{CTRLUP}")
    Sleep(1000)
EndFunc   ;==>ctrla
Local $folderpath = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt"
Local $inpath = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\i.txt"
Local $outpath = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\o.txt"

Func cliptoinpath()
    Send("{LWINDOWN}r{LWINUP}")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("notepad" & @CRLF)
    ;ctrlv()
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}")
    Sleep(1000)
    ;   ctrlshfts()
    Send("{CTRLDOWN}{SHIFTDOWN}s{SHIFTUP}{CTRLUP}")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send($inpath)
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("{ENTER}")
    Sleep(1000)
    ;altf4()
    Send("{ALTDOWN}{F4}{ALTUP}")
    Sleep(1000)
EndFunc   ;==>cliptoinpath

Local $removelines = "powershell -join ""\""$(Get-Content " & $inpath & ")""\""""" & "{>}" & $outpath & @CRLF
Local $outtoclip
Func removelines()
    Sleep(1000)
    ;do not winwait
    Send("{LWINDOWN}r{LWINUP}")
    Sleep(1000)
    Send("cmd" & @CRLF)
    Sleep(1000)
    Send($removelines & @CRLF)
    Sleep(1000)
EndFunc   ;==>removelines
Func removenewlinesfromclip()
    $CMD = "echo y | del " & $folderpath & "" & @CRLF
    RunWait(@ComSpec & " /V:ON /c " & $CMD)
    $CMD = "mkdir " & $folderpath & " " & @CRLF
    RunWait(@ComSpec & " /V:ON /c " & $CMD)
    cliptoinpath()
    $CMD = "ipconfig > " & $outpath & ""
    RunWait(@ComSpec & " /V:ON /c " & $CMD)
    removelines()
    $outtoclip = "type " & $outpath & " |clip"
    RunWait(@ComSpec & " /V:ON /c " & $outtoclip)
EndFunc   ;==>removenewlinesfromclip

;
While 1
    Local $pdf = "PDF"
    Local $pingclip
    Local $origional
    Local $firstThreeInClip = StringMid(ClipGet(), 1, 3)
    Local $firstFourInClip = StringMid(ClipGet(), 1, 4)
    Local $http = "http"
    If $firstFourInClip = $http And $origional <> ClipGet() Then
        TrimItDown()
    ElseIf $firstThreeInClip = $pdf And $origional <> StringMid(ClipGet(), 1, 3) Then
        $origional = StringMid(ClipGet(), 1, 3)
        ;set paths
        Local $folderpath = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt"
        Local $inpath = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\i.txt"
        Local $outpath = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\tt\o.txt"
        ;save clipboard to a .txt
        ;remove lines
        ;use this code in cmd when removing lines
        ;powershell -command "\"$(Get-Content file.txt)\" > newFile.txt"
        Local $removelines = "powershell -join ""\""$(Get-Content " & $inpath & ")""\""""" & "{>}" & $outpath & @CRLF
        Local $outtoclip
        removenewlinesfromclip()
        Local $sString = StringReplace(ClipGet(), " ", "!")
        ClipPut($sString)
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", ClipGet() & @CRLF & "in clipboard")
    Else
        Sleep(200)
    EndIf
WEnd

;url to page func
Func urltopage()
    $sData1 = ClipGet()
    $sString1 = StringReplace($sData1, "https://www.", Null)
    ClipPut($sString1)
    $sData1 = ClipGet()
    $sData2 = ClipGet()
    $sString2 = StringReplace($sData2, "https://", Null)
    ClipPut($sString2)
    $sData2 = ClipGet()
    $sData3 = ClipGet()
    $sString3 = StringReplace($sData3, "http://www.", Null)
    ClipPut($sString3)
    $sData3 = ClipGet()
    $sData4 = ClipGet()
    $sString4 = StringReplace($sData4, "http://", Null)
    ClipPut($sString4)
    $sData4 = ClipGet()
EndFunc   ;==>urltopage

;url to site func
Func urltosite()
    $sData1 = ClipGet()
    $sString1 = StringReplace($sData1, "https://www.", Null)
    ClipPut($sString1)
    $sData1 = ClipGet()
    $sData2 = ClipGet()
    $sString2 = StringReplace($sData2, "https://", Null)
    ClipPut($sString2)
    $sData2 = ClipGet()
    $sData3 = ClipGet()
    $sString3 = StringReplace($sData3, "http://www.", Null)
    ClipPut($sString3)
    $sData3 = ClipGet()
    $sData4 = ClipGet()
    $sString4 = StringReplace($sData4, "http://", Null)
    ClipPut($sString4)
    $sData4 = ClipGet()
    $url = ClipGet()
    $spliturl = StringSplit($url, '/')
    $site = $spliturl[1]
    ClipPut($site)
EndFunc   ;==>urltosite

;url to ip func
Func urltoip()
    ;trim to site
    $sData1 = ClipGet()
    $sString1 = StringReplace($sData1, "https://www.", Null)
    ClipPut($sString1)
    $sData1 = ClipGet()
    $sData2 = ClipGet()
    $sString2 = StringReplace($sData2, "https://", Null)
    ClipPut($sString2)
    $sData2 = ClipGet()
    $sData3 = ClipGet()
    $sString3 = StringReplace($sData3, "http://www.", Null)
    ClipPut($sString3)
    $sData3 = ClipGet()
    $sData4 = ClipGet()
    $sString4 = StringReplace($sData4, "http://", Null)
    ClipPut($sString4)
    $sData4 = ClipGet()
    $url = ClipGet()
    $spliturl = StringSplit($url, '/')
    $site = $spliturl[1]
    ClipPut($site)
    ;use this for realtime testing
    ;https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/HotKeySet.htm
    $CMD = "ping " & ClipGet() & " | clip"
    RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c " & $CMD)
    ;save ping clip to $pingclip
    $pingclip = ClipGet()
    ;split string pinglip to second substring with '[' as paraneter
    $pingclip = StringSplit($pingclip, '[')
    $pingclip = $pingclip[2]
    ;split string pinglip to first substring with ']' as paraneter
    $pingclip = StringSplit($pingclip, ']')
    $pingclip = $pingclip[1]
    ClipPut($pingclip)
EndFunc   ;==>urltoip



Func BulkLoad(Const $sDelim = '!', Const $sSearch = '.', Const $iDelay = 250)
    Local Const $sInput = ClipGet()
    Local Const $aArray = StringSplit($sInput, $sDelim)

    For $i1 = 1 To $aArray[0]

        If Not StringInStr($aArray[$i1], $sSearch) Then ContinueLoop

        ClipPut($aArray[$i1])
        Send('^v')
        Sleep($iDelay)
        Send('{ENTER}')
        Sleep($iDelay)

    Next

EndFunc

;bulkload tutorial func
Func loaderTutorial()
    ;Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe " & $CmdLine[0])
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Position the cursor where load sequence will begin")
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Press Ctrl + Shift + d to deploy.")
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "This hotkey is always active")
EndFunc   ;==>loaderTutorial

Func TrimItDown()
    GUICreate("StringTools", 460, 145)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Please select", 1, 1)
    Local $idButton_Page = GUICtrlCreateButton("Page", 10, 25, 140, 50)
    Local $idButton_Site = GUICtrlCreateButton("Site", 160, 25, 140, 50)
    Local $idButton_Origional = GUICtrlCreateButton("Ignore", 310, 25, 140, 50)
    Local $idButton_ip = GUICtrlCreateButton("IP", 10, 90, 140, 50)
    ;Local $idButton_BulkLoad = GUICtrlCreateButton("Bulk Load", 95, 90, 100, 50)
    Local $idButton_bulkloadTutorial = GUICtrlCreateButton("Bulk Load Tutorial", 160, 90, 140, 50)
    Local $idButton_Exit = GUICtrlCreateButton("Exit", 310, 90, 140, 50)


    ;Local $aAccelKeys[5][5] = [["^!+y", $idButton_Page], ["^!+n", $idButton_Site], ["^!+t", $idButton_Origional], ["^!+u", $idButton_ip], ["^!+u", $idButton_Exit]]
    ;GUISetAccelerators($aAccelKeys)
    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW) ; Display the GUI.

    While 1
        Switch GUIGetMsg()
            Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                Send("{Esc}")
                GUIDelete()
                ExitLoop
            Case $idButton_Page
                urltopage()
                ExitLoop
            Case $idButton_Site
                urltosite()
                ExitLoop
            Case $idButton_Origional
                $origional = ClipGet()
                ExitLoop
            Case $idButton_ip
                urltoip()
                ExitLoop
            Case $idButton_bulkloadTutorial
                loaderTutorial()
                ExitLoop
            Case $idButton_Exit
                Send("{Esc}")
                ExitLoop
        EndSwitch
    WEnd
    GUIDelete()
EndFunc   ;==>TrimItDown

;test string
#cs
PDF

wikkipedia.ord
snapfish.com
.tunnelbear.com
mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
google.com/url?q=https://connect.cloudberrylab.com?i%3D448781782&source=gmail&ust=1573146628917000&usg=AFQjCNF14Y-dux0_bNSOc-jOfjLgHy-3fw

#ce
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*bottom line: i want my code to stop outputting strings that do not have a period inside of them.*"

Possibly :

```
If Not StringInStr($aArray[$i1], $sSearch) Then ContinueLoop
```

Example :

```
Func BulkLoad(Const $sDelim = '!', Const $sSearch = '.', Const $iDelay = 250)
    Local Const $sInput = ClipGet()
    Local Const $aArray = StringSplit($sInput, $sDelim)

    For $i1 = 1 To $aArray[0]

        If Not StringInStr($aArray[$i1], $sSearch) Then ContinueLoop

        ClipPut($aArray[$i1])
        Send('^v')
        Sleep($iDelay)
        Send('{ENTER}')
        Sleep($iDelay)

    Next

EndFunc
```

Example to be called from [`HotKeySet()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/HotKeySet.htm) (without function parameters):

```
Func BulkLoad()
    Local Const $iDelay  = 250
    Local Const $sDelim  = '!', _
                $sSearch = '.', _
                $sInput  = ClipGet()
    Local Const $aArray  = StringSplit($sInput, $sDelim)

    For $i1 = 1 To $aArray[0]

        If Not StringInStr($aArray[$i1], $sSearch) Then ContinueLoop

        ClipPut($aArray[$i1])
        Send('^v')
        Sleep($iDelay)
        Send('{ENTER}')
        Sleep($iDelay)

    Next

EndFunc
```